# How to prompt browser to display open/save dialog box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, browser, dialog

How to prompt browser to display open/save dialog box using jquery?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want the user to "save" something, you need to send a http response from the server with the correct content-type or define as "attachment". If you want the user to "open" something, only a <input type=file /> tag will allow this - and JS will not be able to access the file, it must be POSTed to the server. That is, this can only be done by server actions, not javascript actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not possible.** The browsers handle that specifically so that hackers can't force you to download a virus, which would be much easier for them if it happened in javascript.

Comment: @sarfraz any other possibilty to do it in asp.net?

Comment: @bala3569: asp.net is server-side language, it can not interact directly with the browsers. So I am sorry there is no chance in that either.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in situations such as this is open an invisible iFrame on the page using javascript, which opens a page with the apprepriate HTTP headers:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=genome.jpeg;`

naturally change "genome.jpg" to the appropriate default filename.